# Does .hash section size in an object affect performance

Tags: c++, performance, hash

I am observing a performance penalty just by compiling few more C++ files in a .SO. The .hash section size before the files (1 .hash         00002e7c) and after adding files is (1 .hash         000041f0). Can this cause performance issues? 
As per this link https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/the_cost_of_elf_symbol it can. Request someone to comment and give some pointers on how to avoid this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you affected by your linker's performance somehow?  Linking is taking too long?

Comment: Every time i run a this executable i see the performance difference. But if i just dont link these C++ objects i get back the performance.

Comment: You haven't given us much to go on.  You imply you're not actually using/calling anything from the extra objects, just linking the SO they're in and using other symbols in it?  Firstly, why are these extra C++ files defining such a large number of external symbols?  Can you make some static?  Secondly, the blog you link says lookup of a symbol involves iterating a list doing hash lookups - if you put your new symbols at the end of the list then they shouldn't have any significant cost on lookup of the other symbols: I don't know how much control you have, but try reordering the `.o`s.

Comment: Separately, it's possible that the degradation in performance relates to lower cache hits when accessing other parts of the shared object, or some runtime static object creation or initialisation code that's invoked on loading - you should instrument your code to see exactly where/when the slowdown is happening.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I am just linking and not using any symbols in it. I already did what you have suggested, making whatever possible as static. With the static change the CPU time is reduced. What I am unable to explain is why CPU time increasing, doesn't linking happens only once? My program is continuously running, I submit a job and measure CPU time for the job. Static initialization code should not execute every time i submit a job since the executable is already in running state.